ASP.NET Core 8 data protection: A key with (name/id) keyname was not found in this key vault
I set up ASP.NET Core 8 DataProtection as described in the article below with Azure Blob Storage to persist the keys and Azure Key Vault to protect the keys.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0
The application is hosted as a Docker container in an Azure App Service (Web App) and uses .NET 8.0.
The setup is done as follows:
var dataProtectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection();
string dataProtectionContainerName = "somecontainername";
string dataProtectionBlobName = "someblobname";
dataProtectionBuilder = dataProtectionBuilder.PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage((serviceProvider) => {
    var blobServiceClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BlobServiceClient>();
    var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(dataProtectionContainerName);
    blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(dataProtectionBlobName);
    return blobClient;
});

Uri keyIdentifierUri = new Uri(new Uri($"https://somevault.vault.azure.net/"), "keys/keyname/");

TokenCredential azureTokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
dataProtectionBuilder = dataProtectionBuilder.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(keyIdentifierUri, azureTokenCredential);

string applicationName = "someapplication";
dataProtectionBuilder.SetApplicationName(applicationName);

These are the packages that I'm using:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs" Version="1.3.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Keys" Version="1.2.3" />

I keep getting the error below:

A key with (name/id) keyname was not found in this key vault. If you recently deleted this key you may be able to recover it using the correct recovery command. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125182
Status: 404 (Not Found)
ErrorCode: KeyNotFound
Content:
{"error":{"code":"KeyNotFound","message":"A key with (name/id) keyname was not found in this key vault. If you recently deleted this key you may be able to recover it using the correct recovery command. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125182"}}
Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
x-ms-keyvault-region: REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id: REDACTED
x-ms-request-id: REDACTED
x-ms-keyvault-service-version: 1.9.1380.1
x-ms-keyvault-network-info: conn_type=Ipv4;addr=REDACTED;act_addr_fam=REDACTED;
x-ms-keyvault-rbac-assignment-id: REDACTED
X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2024 11:24:15 GMT
Content-Length: 302
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1

When I look in the Azure Key Vault, there is no key with that name and when I look in Azure Blob Storage, the blob is also not there.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
I was expecting the ASP.NET Core 8 DataProtection to create the key automatically if it doesn't exist. Am I wrong in my assumption?

I implemented a workaround fix using ProtectKeysWithCertificate instead of ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault. However, I'm still interesting in a solution with ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault.

Did you check that your account with which you're logging in has both the secrets/list and secrets/get permissions?
